# Start the app through the puppet with params based on the fact

Tags: java, puppet

I have a part in *init.pp*, that starts my app:

```
systemd::service {'app':
    user => 'java',
    exec => "${java_home}/bin/java \
    -server \
    '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\\'kill -9 %%p\\'' \
    -Dmw.config=/etc/app/app.config \
    -cp /usr/share/app/app.jar ru.app.main.Main app",
}
```

The newer version of the *app.jar* starts differently. There's a way, stop the puppet on the nodes, deregister the node from the consul, start the puppet with the new *init.pp*, and put that node back to the consul. But that just doesn't feel right.

Is there a way to put some **"if"** in there so I'd be able to make smooth transitions back and forth depending on my app's version or any other field?

Comment: are you trying to start different version of jar across several nodes ?

Comment: for some time, yes. So could be able to deploy a new version, test it and rollback to the old one if I needed without changing a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it

```
if $app_v2 == 'true' {
        systemd::service {'app':
            user => 'java',
            exec => "${java_home}/bin/java \
            -server \
            '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\\'kill -9 %%p\\'' \
            -Dmw.config=/etc/app/app_new.config \
            -cp /usr/share/app/app.jar ru.app.main.App app",
        }
    } else {
        systemd::service {'app':
            user => 'java',
            exec => "${java_home}/bin/java \
            -server \
            '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\\'kill -9 %%p\\'' \
            -Dmw.config=/etc/app/app.config \
            -cp /usr/share/app/app.jar ru.app.main.Main app",
        }
    }
```

and for getting app_v2 flag, add to /lib/facter/app_v2.rb

```
require 'facter'

Facter.add(:app_v2) do
  confine :kernel => :Linux
  setcode do
    result = false
    if Facter::Core::Execution.exec('dpkg -l | grep app|awk \'{print$3}\'| cut -c1') == '2'
      result = true
    end
    result
  end
end
```